# Can anonymized teaching evaluations be made public in the United States?

Tags: united-states, course-evaluation, teaching-statement

Can anonymized teaching evaluations be made (legally) publicly available by the teacher who received them in the United States? For example, I have seen a fair amount of teaching statement containing anonymized teaching evaluations in faculty applications, and some of these teaching statements are publicly available (e.g., placed on the applicant's website)

Comment: There could be copyright issues, especially if a lengthy comment is quoted in its entirety, but it seems farfetched to imagine that the student would actually sue. When I've been on hiring committees, applicants have frequently sent a page of comments quoted from evaluations. IMO the real problem isn't legal, it's just that it's a dumb idea. A potential employer knows that the applicant is cherry-picking the comments.

Comment: Related: [University policy of publishing student course evaluations: Prevalence and pros and cons](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/university-policy-of-publishing-student-course-evaluations-prevalence-and-pros)

Comment: @BenCrowell [Is it useful to add excerpts from teaching evaluations in a teaching statement?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/85439/452)

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate because the question linked by @MadJack shows cases where these are being made publicly available without apparent objection.