# Is it useful to add excerpts from teaching evaluations in a teaching statement?

Tags: faculty-application, course-evaluation, teaching-statement

Is it useful to add excerpts from teaching evaluations in a teaching statement included in a faculty application?

A fair amount of teaching statements seem to contain some, but since excerpts are  typically cherry picked I wonder whether the admission committee cares about them.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an article that surveys how teaching is evaluated in a mathematics faculty search (YMMV in different fields). Based on this, in general, teaching evaluations are valued, even if they are not asked for. This leads me to think that including information from evaluations (e.g. comments but also summarized numerical ratings) is a good practice.

http://www.ams.org/notices/200710/tx071001308p.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I think that including excerpts from teaching evaluations alone may not that valuable since, as you say, the excerpts can be cherry-picked. If you also add  the mean ratings along with standard deviations, the excerpts will have more weight, IMO. In addition, if these numbers and excerpts can be used to support that your teaching philosophy is contributing to improved learning in the classroom, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

The question is best approached by looking at how sales and marketing organizations work; after all, you're selling yourself by applying for a position on the faculty and the way to be successful is by using proven sales strategies.

Marketing organizations know that customer testimonials are probably the MOST effective way to earn a new customer's business. The evidence is everywhere: TV commercials, online advertising, print media, etc. Present a client talking about how your product or service went beyond expectations, and new clients will feel a level of confidence in signing on with you.

So, YES, include testimonials, but do so in a way that's understated - NOT cocky!